# Can I resolve an issue's sub-task using a FishEye smart commit?

Tags: tools

### Context

I have a feature request represented as a JIRA issue with the handle **PRJ-11**. My issue has a sub-task with the handle **PRJ-23**. JIRA has the latest FishEye and FishEye Plugin installed and smart commits are enabled.

### Question

If I was to make an SVN commit with the log message:

> PRJ-11 #resolve #time 1w #comment Finished working on the complete feature

FishEye would resolve the parent issue (and presumably the sub-task while it was at it).

If I try to do the same with the sub-task:

> PRJ-23 #resolve #time 1w #comment Finished working on the sub-task

FishEye detects the SVN commit and logs the activity against the sub-task, **but** it does not either advance the workflow of the sub-task or log any time against it or the parent issue.

Have I missed something in my commit message syntax or FishEye configuration?

Comment: If this is the right place to post a question like this, I'd appreciate someone with more rep creating a JIRA tag :)

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure this is the right place. Project managers really don't use version control, developers do... I'll give this awhile to see if there's more input from the community in regards to this question.

Comment: Cheers - I was thinking on the same lines to be honest, but wanted to see what response I got from the community. There's also a meta-question related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151412/is-stackoverflow-the-right-place-to-ask-technical-questions-about-jira-configu#comment434142_151412

Comment: According to SO Mods, this would be on topic on SO, so if this doesn't get any answers here in the next few days, or it gets closed here, just flag it and we'll move it for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Jira workflow is not setup to do what you expect. I suppose that when you manually resolve a sub-task in Jira, the parent's issue does not get resolved. You need  to add a post action for Resolve transition.

You may be interested in [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin. In particular - 'All sub-tasks must be resolved condition'. So you can set status of the parent issue on condition of all sub tasks closed.